# How to make a printer visible to two different subnets?

Tags: routing, switch, hp, 3-com

How are you? I hope well.

As you can see by the tittle I'm in the middle of a situation that i have to access a print in another subnet. These subnets are operating in different switches(Switch A and Switch B), the devices connected to the switch A are getting IP from a server and the devices connected to the switch B are getting the IP from a DSL Modem. I made a research and i found these specific 3com models are 3 Layers switches. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Routers route traffic between networks. You must route traffic using a router, or a layer-3 switch (layer-3 switches have an internal router, but you probably need to enable routing).

Comment: I need create some VLAN or just IP Routing can solve this problem?

Comment: Just routing between the networks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need to link the two physically separate networks and route them. If the Layer3 switches are capable then you could do it there however the route should be added on whatever is serving as the default gateway to clients.

If 'printer visibility' is what you are looking for on desktop clients, then this will only ever work in the same subnet as its discovery/broadcast based. Adding any printers outside of the local subnet has to be done manually, it won't just appear in your 'nearby printers' list.